# Difference in Add View dialog box in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, visual-studio-2015

I've searched for similar questions already and couldn't find something close to my issue.
While I was using VS 2013 Community I used to have a nice Add View dialog box, in which you could specify the view engine, scaffolding and other useful things alongside with your views in MVC projects. But now, in VS 2015 Community edition, that dialog box has changed from:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/buEKJ.png - VS 2013 window (desired) 
to 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIpti.png - VS 2015 window (current)

Now, I've seen one of my mates at work using VS 2015 Community (same version - 14.0.24720.00 Update 1) , that actually has the other Add View dialog box, therefore it must be a setting of some kind in order to get the desired dialog box.  Does anyone know to tweak the IDE so that it can show the desired Add View window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be related to the MVC version being used, which could include helper dialogs like this. I'm not sure how to switch or revert, this would probably involve removing MVC 5 from the system and then installing an older version, which I would hesitate to recommend.

Anyway, if you choose Template `Empty` instead of `Empty (with model)` then it will make a strong typed view. The Model class can be selected below it. It is just a slightly different approach.

You can also choose another Template and get scaffolded code for your Model class.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the MVC version. We both use MVC 5 in our projects, but he has the "good looking" and far more useful dialog box. I know how to use the current one, but I find the "old" one far better in every way possible.